# NFC implementation on fpga

Tags: nfc

Is it possible to build a NFC transceiver on a FPGA ? 
If yes what kind of signal conditioning will it require to take data in and out of the FPGA.
Basically what size(LUTS) fpga will be able to handle a NFC transceiver may be not fully fledged but a lite version.

Comment: can we interface an antenna to an fpga

Comment: See related link for NFC transceiver chipsets. Perhaps one could use an external NFC chipset, managed by an FPGA or microcontroller? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15810/how-to-add-nfc-to-a-cheap-consumer-product?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. NFC requires RF circuitry including an antenna. A FPGA by itself isn't enough.

Comment: There are RF FPGAs available.